# C++, правильное написание метода, реализующего release() семантику

Tags: c++, move, rvalue

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
class Object
{
    public:
    // ...

    private:
    Something something;
}
```

Я хочу, чтобы `Object` предоставлял метод `release()`, название которого исчерпывающе описывает его семантику.

Например, мы могли бы написать нужный метод так:

```
Something&& release()
{
    return std::move(something);
}
```

Или вот так:

```
Something release()
{
    return std::move(something);
}
```

Есть ли какие-то отличия между двумя этими вариантами?

Я тысячи раз писал подобный код, но только сейчас задумался над тем, что же в действительности происходит.

Comment: Первый вариант ничего не гарантирует - вызывающая сторона может не переместить значение, тогда `something` останется в исходном состоянии. И многое зависит от самого Something. Что это и как оно реализует перемещение.

Comment: ...а во втором случае даже если вызывающая сторона ничего не сделает с объектом, который вернет `release()`, значение `something` будет потеряно.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat в этом смысл release. Текущий объект отказывается от something. Если никто не хочет с ним больше нянчиться, то пусть помрет героем.